# How to render latex in-line with org mode?

Tags: latex, org-mode

I have a file with the following contents:

```
Math Notes -*- mode: org -*-
#+STARTUP: latexpreview

Test $\forall \epsilon > 0$
```

I am trying to render the latex with C-c C-x C-l, but it's not working.
Could someone please offer some advise on how to debug this? Thanks!

Comment: Any error message? (also your link is not working)

Comment: There is no error message, it just doesn't render in-line. I tried this again with an empty .emacs.d directory and the same result.

Comment: I cannot reproduce, sorry. Maybe you can tell us what is your emacs version and if you are running under Linux, Windows... (I am running Emacs 26.1, org 9.1.9, Debian on my side)

Comment: I am using GNU Emacs 26.3 on Mac OS 10.12.5.